# j!dump: How do I track where a class is defined?

Tags: php, extensions

I am a beginner with  PHP and Joomla Core development. This great extension helps me a lot during my learning.
A very frequent situation when I try to understand some code is, there is a method of a class being invoked in a line and I want to look into the definition of the class but have no idea where it is. Before j!dump, I had to download the extension in question and in-text search the class, which takes a lot of time. I believe this simple goal can be achieved by using j!dump, but I don't know how. It is like follows:

```
$messages = modPimediaplayerHelper::getStudy($params);
```

This line is found in a module's PHP file, I'd like to know where this `modPimediaplayerHelper` is defined, I tried `dump(modPimediaplayerHelper)` and `dump(modPimediaplayerHelper::getStudy)`, both of them don't work, so what should I do?

By the way, when I try to `dump($params)`, it returns a object without meaningful properties but only methods, which provokes me to look into how this $params object is defined also, how do I use J!dump to track it?

Comment: You would therefor do. var_dump($params);

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find out where the class is defined using **JDump**

You can find out if from inside a running method using **dumpTrace();**, but not outside of a class.

To get what you need try this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420066/finding-the-php-file-at-run-time-where-a-class-was-defined

BTW, have you visited Joomla JDump backend? **/administrator/index.php?option=com_dump** There is a couple of JDump options there maybe useful in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

As you're referring to a module which is (in my own opinion), the most simple type of extension, I'll answer this for a module only.

Most modules have a *helper.php* file which contains function that retrieve data to be displayed in the module output, so basically, everything that happens behind the scenes.

This is where your class `modPimediaplayerHelper` will be defined.

So you simply need to look in the following directory:

ROOT/modules/mod_pmedia_player_helper/helper.php

**Note:** I used `mod_pmedia_player_helper` in the path as a guess. It may be slightly different but definitely something along these lines.

Hope this helps